# Why do protons in the atom need to communicate with electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, atomic-physics

Why do the protons need to communicate to electrons via electromagnetism if electrons don’t do anything except orbiting the nucleus?

Comment: Why would electrons orbit the nucleus if the protons did not have an electromagnetic effect on them?

Comment: Who says they are "communicating"? Why would "just orbiting" require (or not require) such communication? Do you mean "interact" and not "communicate"?

Answer (score 0):

Protons and electrons have electric charge so they will interact with each other via electromagnetic force. They are coupled electromagnetically. The atom orbitals are obtained by solving the Schrodinger equation that takes into account the Coulomb potential between the proton and the electron. If they hadn't been coupled electromagnetically, the atoms would not have formed.